# Why, when I add the "active" class to my sass styles, it doesn't take and display the "after" style?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

Before I give the **active **class to the tag, the **after **style works and puts the line under the text, but after I add the active class to the tag, the **after **doesn't work anymore. Where did I go wrong?
I use React js and scss(module.scss)

[without active class, ::after works and show the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJgwh.png)

[with active class, ::after doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmEDI.png)

```jsx
<Row>
  <Col>
    <div className={`${styles.lgtTab}`}>
      <div className={`${styles.tabNav}`}>
        <div className={`d-inline-block me-4 py-2 active ${styles.tabHeaderItem}`}>
          <i className="bi bi-list-check me-2"></i>
          <a href="#productFeatures">Product Features</a>
        </div>
        <div className={`d-inline-block me-4 py-2 ${styles.tabHeaderItem}`}>
          <i className="bi bi-justify-left me-2"></i>
          <a href="#moreDetails">More Details</a>
        </div>
        <div className={`d-inline-block me-4 py-2 ${styles.tabHeaderItem}`}>
          <i className="bi bi-question-square me-2"></i>
          <a href="#askFromSeller">Ask From the Seller</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={`py-4 pe-4`}>
        <div id="productFeatures" className={`${styles.tabContent}`}>
          <h3>Product Features</h3>
          <Table striped bordered className={`mx-4 ${styles.lgtTable}`}>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something else</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something else</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something else</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something else</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        <div id="moreDetails" className={`${styles.tabContent}`}>
          <h3>More Details</h3>
          <p className={`mx-4`}>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt eum ipsam quod nostrum repudiandae,
            a fugit reprehenderit necessitatibus eos.
            Similique eaque odio quasi cumque rerum doloribus eius, fugiat enim quibusdam?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="askFromSeller" className={`${styles.tabContent}`}>
          <h3>Ask From the Seller</h3>
          <span className={`mx-4`}>
            Log in to your account to ask the seller of this product. <a href="#" className={`text-decoration-none ${styles.lgtLoginLink}`}>Login / Register</a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

scss style:

```scss
.tabNav{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
    .tabHeaderItem{
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
        position: relative;
            a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: var(--bs-gray-600);
            }
        &.active{
            &::after{
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 41px;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 5px;
                border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
                background-color: $primary;
                -webkit-transition: height .3s,opacity .15s;
                -o-transition: height .3s,opacity .15s;
                transition: height .3s,opacity .15s;
                bottom: 0px;
                right: 0px;
            }
            a{
                color: var(--bs-body-color);
            }
        }
        i{
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who/where is the active class being set? Are you certain it is being set?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my answer to address the point you made.

One thing you can do is make use of the `:not` selector.

You can see in the snippet (and SCSS code below) that I only add the `::after` style for `a` elements that are `:not` within `.tabHeaderItem.active`

```css
.tabNav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}
.tabNav .tabHeaderItem {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}
.tabNav .tabHeaderItem a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  // color: var(--bs-gray-600);
}
.tabNav .tabHeaderItem:not(.active) a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  background-color: red;
  // background-color: $primary;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.15s;
  -o-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.15s;
  transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.15s;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.tabNav .tabHeaderItem.active a {
  // color: var(--bs-body-color);
  color: black;
}
.tabNav .tabHeaderItem i {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<Row>
  <Col>
    <div class="lgtTab">
      <div class="tabNav">
        <div class="d-inline-block me-4 py-2 active tabHeaderItem">
          <i class="bi bi-list-check me-2"></i>
          <a href="#productFeatures">Product Features</a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-block me-4 py-2 tabHeaderItem">
          <i class="bi bi-justify-left me-2"></i>
          <a href="#moreDetails">More Details</a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-block me-4 py-2 tabHeaderItem"}>
          <i class="bi bi-question-square me-2"></i>
          <a href="#askFromSeller">Ask From the Seller</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="py-4 pe-4">
        <div id="productFeatures" class="tabContent">
          <h3>Product Features</h3>
          <Table striped bordered class="mx-4 lgtTable">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something else</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something else</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something else</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something else</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        <div id="moreDetails" className="tabContent">
          <h3>More Details</h3>
          <p className="mx-4">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt eum ipsam quod nostrum repudiandae,
            a fugit reprehenderit necessitatibus eos.
            Similique eaque odio quasi cumque rerum doloribus eius, fugiat enim quibusdam?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="askFromSeller" className="tabContent"}>
          <h3>Ask From the Seller</h3>
          <span className={`mx-4`}>
            Log in to your account to ask the seller of this product. <a href="#" className="text-decoration-none lgtLoginLink">Login / Register</a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

```scss
.tabNav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
    .tabHeaderItem {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
        position: relative;
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: var(--bs-gray-600);
        }
        &:not(.active) {
            a {
                &::after {
                    content: "";
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 41px;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 5px;
                    border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
                    background-color: $primary;
                    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.15s;
                    -o-transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.15s;
                    transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.15s;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    right: 0px;
                }
            }
        }
        i {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    }
    .tabHeaderItem.active {
        a {
            color: var(--bs-body-color);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I put the wrong code here. I updated now and put the correct code. Can you tell me where my mistake is now, please?

Comment: @Setare you want the same `:after` styling when `active` is there and not there? So the only difference would be the colour of the link?

Comment: I want to show the **after** style when the tab **is active**, but it should not be shown when the tab is not active. @harrison